# What is the recommended django project structure?

Tags: django, project-structure

I haven't exactly found the answer to this, maybe there is no best one. Django docs are not clear on this thing.

I'm not sure what is a good practice to set up a django project. Sure I have re-usable apps. But I always need some glue-code.

I find myself always creating "core" app for each project, which usually serves homepape.

Then in project url config I do something like this:

```
(r'^/$', include(core.urls))
```

Is this the way to go? Or do you have a better idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it's a good idea to use a glue app/module that also contains further helper functions/reusable code (if any), however I'm not sure if that's the way the other djangonauts do these kind of stuff.

Also, in order to match the homepage I think that the correct regexp is r'^$'. With the above solution you propose, you'll have to be careful because **every** url defined in core.urls will be 'mounted' under your site's root directory.

Also, and for the case of the homepage I used something like this

```
(r'^$', 'apps.core.views.homepage')
```

just to distinguish this url. I guess it's just a matter of how one wants things organized.

Answer (score 1):

Don't put the slash and the dollar. This is how I did it.

```
(r'^', include('core.urls')),
```

You're already on the right track. ;)

Answer (score 1):

The approach you mention is a good one. I tend to stash away stuff like that into a `views.py` file in the root of the project. There is already a `urls.py` in the root folder.