# Django 1.4 project layout: Using mysite as the glue app

Tags: django

The old [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1629515/what-is-the-recommended-django-project-structure?rq=1) for Django project layout specifies that it's good practice to make a `glue` application that ties in data from various other applications (e.g. for the home page).

Now that Django 1.4 automatically creates the `../project_name/project_name/` folder, should I use the `project_name` application as the `glue` application? Or should I still make a `core` app and leave the automatically created `project_name` application alone?

Comment: I think you should specify more in detail what you intend to put there, because _frontpage_ for instance could be an app as well... The  project layout should depend on how complex your whole project is...

Answer (score 0):

Over the last couple of projects, I've found the following layout to work quite well:

The `common` folder above contains all the stuff that doesn't really fit elsewhere, including the base `urls.py`, `sitemaps.py`, general template tags, general context processors and so on. I find this pretty clean and easy to maintain. Most importantly, the entire directory can be easily checked into git.

I wouldn't worry about the default layout for 1.4. Do whatever suits you.

```
- apps/ 
  - /foo_app
  - /bar_app
- common # The equivalent of the glue app you talk about
- confs # Uwsgi/supervisor/nginx/gunicorn etc. configurations
  - /production  
  - /staging
  - /dev
- docs
- fixtures
- media
- static
- requirements # for `pip freeze > ...`
  - /production 
  - /staging
  - /development
- scripts
- settings
  - private.py # Secret Key etc., not put on VCS
  - database.py # DB Settings, also no in VCS
  - development.py
  - production.py
  - staging.py
  - default.py # All Django's settings
  - custom.py # Custom application settings
- templates
```

Comment: I'm coming from 1.3 and finding this whole new structure to be quite confusing as well. I'm guessing then, that you delete the sub folder that django-admin makes automatically, as I'm not seeing that here?

Comment: Where do you place the `manage.py` in this structure of yours?

Comment: I don't use the `manage.py`, I set the paths and settings via virtualenv and just use `django-admin.py` instead